# Find the value present in more than one date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table similar to this. I want to find the users active in more than one department at any time in this data. Please suggest the SQL query for this. In the below example, U1 will need to be returned as U1 was active from 2021-04-01 to 2021-12-31 in more than one department

```
+--------+------------+----------------+--------------+
| UserId | Department | ActiveFromDate | ActiveToDate |
+--------+------------+----------------+--------------+
| U1     | D1         | 2021-01-01     | 2021-12-31   |
+--------+------------+----------------+--------------+
| U1     | D2         | 2021-04-01     | 2022-12-31   |
+--------+------------+----------------+--------------+
| U2     | D2         | 2021-01-01     | 2021-03-31   |
+--------+------------+----------------+--------------+
| U3     | D1         | 2021-01-01     | 2022-12-31   |
+--------+------------+----------------+--------------+
| U2     | D1         | 2021-04-01     | 2022-12-31   |
+--------+------------+----------------+--------------+
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I tried making a join like this. I know this won't give me all the records. I am not sure which SQL operators can be used to get the correct results.
            select * from table1 a inner join table1 b on a.userid = b.userid and a.activefromdate <= b.activefromdate and  a.departmentId <> b.departmentId
and a.activeTodate >= b.activeToDate

Comment: Edit any clarifications into your question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired result using self-join and the below query

Sample Table and Data:

```
CREATE TABLE SampleData (
  UserId VARCHAR(50),
  Department VARCHAR(50),
  ActiveFromDate DATE,
  ActiveToDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO SampleData (UserId, Department, ActiveFromDate, ActiveToDate)
VALUES 
  ('U1', 'D1', '2021-01-01', '2021-12-31'),
  ('U1', 'D2', '2021-04-01', '2022-12-31'),
  ('U2', 'D2', '2021-01-01', '2021-03-31'),
  ('U3', 'D1', '2021-01-01', '2022-12-31'),
  ('U2', 'D1', '2021-04-01', '2022-12-31');
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.UserId
FROM SampleData a
JOIN SampleData b ON a.UserId = b.UserId 
AND a.Department <> b.Department
WHERE a.ActiveFromDate <= b.ActiveToDate 
AND a.ActiveToDate >= b.ActiveFromDate
```